# Losing Wireless connection or very slow connection

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I've just installed a TP-LINK TL-WN881ND and I face network issues. Connection keeps droping and when I finally get connected my I get like 1 kbps. Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wireless bluetooth mouse was causing some kind of interference, when I removed it everything works as expected. Problem solved.